# beamer theme with navigational circles (bullet points) in header

Tags: beamer, themes

[image]
I want to use a beamer theme for my presentation in beamer like this with fill and empty circle in the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The navigational circles are called `Smoothbars`.
- According to [this](http://latex.artikel-namsu.de/english/themes/outer_smoothbar.html), the theme, **Darmstadt** and **Frankfurt** offer this so-called `outer theme` (`beamer` vocabulary).
- Also useful: http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{SubSection 1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 3}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{SubSection 1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 3}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\subsection{SubSection 1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 3}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection: \insertsubsection}
Some Text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @Dr. Manuel Kuehner,  for taking the time   to answer my questions

Answer (score 3):

Besides all themes based on the `smoothbars` other theme (which are discussed in the answer by Dr. Manuel Kuehner), the themes based on the `mininframes` other theme also have these navigation circles, which are called "miniframes":

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    text
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```